# Pushing data into amazon cloudwatch from nagios

Tags: amazon-web-services, nagios

I dont have access to the Amazon `ec2` instance on which my servers are installed.
My question is how do i get server metrics from ec2 instance into nagios and then monitor it with `amazon cloudwatch` itself.which means pushing monitoring data back to cloudwatch but this without `access id` and `access key`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get metrics form a machine you do not have access to. But once you access the machine, you can configure its monitoring agent so that it sends the metrics to CloudWatch.

Comment: That is because your Nagios server has its agent installed on the machine.

Comment: which agent do you mean nrpe agent.?